# create a BST of string . error

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Inserting just one node to the tree works fine, but on inserting the 2nd node onwards, the program crashes. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
struct node
{
     char* key;
    node *left, *right;
};

// A utility function to create a new BST node
node *newNode(const char* item)
{
    node *temp =new node;
    strcpy(temp->key,item);
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

// A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST
void inorder(node *root)
{
    if (root!= NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        cout<<root->key<<endl;
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

/* A utility function to insert a new node with given key in BST */
node* insert(node* tnode,const char* key)
{
    /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */

    if (tnode == NULL)
        return newNode(key);
    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (strcmp(key,tnode->key) < 0)
        tnode->left  = insert(tnode->left, key);
    else if (strcmp(key,tnode->key) > 0)
        tnode->right = insert(tnode->right, key);

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return tnode;
}

// Driver Program to test above functions*/
int main()
{
    node *root = NULL;
     char* word[]={"elephant","hi","little","nil",NULL};
    root = insert(root,word[0]);                //works fine
for(int i=1;word[i];i++)
    insert(root,word[i]);                                    
// print inoder traversal of the BST
    inorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

after:

root = insert(root,word[0]);

inorder(root);

o/p: elephant

on inserting 2nd node

crashes

Comment: Please, edit your question with proper grammar. Add explanation of what the code is meant to do and what is the actual result.

Comment: Im sorry.
this was my first post

Answer (score 0):

You're not initialising the `key` array that `item` will get copied into. Try this:

```
node *newNode(const char* item)
{
    node *temp = new node();
    temp->key = new char[strlen(item) + 1];
    strcpy(temp->key,item);
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

That said, there are some more problems with your code, like no destructors etc. I'd strongly recommend reading some good books/tutorials on programming in C++.